# LEAST(STRING) and GREATEST(STRING) for long STRINGS in Legacy BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'd like to run the following [SQL query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208633/sql-pair-query) in a BigQuery table:

```
SELECT 
  LEAST(origin, destination) AS point_1,
  GREATEST(origin, destination) AS point_2,
  COUNT(*) AS journey_count,
FROM route
GROUP BY point_1, point_2
ORDER BY point_1, point_2;
```

on a table like:

```
 INSERT INTO route
   ( route_id, origin, destination, dur)
 VALUES 
   ( 1, 'AA', 'BB', 2),
   ( 2, 'CC', 'DD', 4),
   ( 3, 'BB', 'AA', 6),
   ( 4, 'CC', 'AA', 2),
   ( 5, 'DD', 'CC', 12);
```

But BigQuery tells me that, although the query is syntactically correct, `string is not a valid argument type for the LEAST function, for string length > 1.` I tried to cast it to numeric, like `LEAST(cast(origin as numeric), cast(destination as numeric)) AS point_1` but it tells me `LEAST` cannot handle bytes.

How do I make `LEAST` and `GREATEST` compare long strings in BigQuery?

Comment: Are `origin` and `destination` single characters or longer strings?

Comment: @Nick: good point: long strings, I've updated the question

Comment: Just use standard SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
#legacydSQL
SELECT 
  IF(origin < destination, CONCAT(origin, ' - ', destination), CONCAT(destination, ' - ', origin)) route,
  COUNT(1) journey_count
FROM [project:dataset.table]
GROUP BY route   
ORDER BY route
```

if to apply to sample data from your example - result is

```
Row     route       journey_count    
1       AA - BB     2    
2       AA - CC     1    
3       CC - DD     2
```

Answer (score 0):

see this

```
with t as (
   (select 1 as route_id, 'AA' as origin, 'BB' as destination, 2 as dur)
    union all 
   (select 2, 'CC', 'DD', 4)
   union all
   (select 3, 'BB', 'AA', 6)
   union all
   (select 4, 'CC', 'AA', 2) 
   union all
   (select 5, 'DD', 'CC', 12))
select 
   if(origin<destination,origin,destination) as point_1,
   if(origin<destination,destination,origin) as point_2,
   count(1) as journey_count
   from t
GROUP BY point_1, point_2
ORDER BY point_1, point_2;
```